# Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms' on RedHat

Tags: linux, redhat

While creating a local repository and after using `yum repolist` on RedHat 8.1 I got this result

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
AppStream                                        57 MB/s | 5.6 MB     00:00
BaseOS                                           98 MB/s | 2.2 MB     00:00
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS  0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms'
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms'
```

I'm on VmWare and the machine is on host-only for the purpose of my assignement
I also got the same error while running the `dnf install dhcp-server -y`
I tried to restart the virtual machine but nothing changes

I have no clues on the not sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday. But i solved it by unsubscribing and then subscribing the RHEL in subscription app.